# geolocation + ionic native Not working with few android devices

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native, google-geolocation

please help me out from this issue,

geolocation plugin not working with some android devices.
it tested on different Android phones to identify current location on map issues, find below results:

============ I have tested these couple of devices ==========

Coolpad 3600I | Android 6.0.1 | Not working

Redmi note 4 | Android 7, MIUI 9 | Not working

Moto g 3 | Android 6 | Not working

Redmi note 4 | Android 7, MIUI 9 | Not working

Redmi 4 | Android 7.1.2, MIUI 9.1 | working

Moto G4 Plus | Android 7.0 | working

MI Note 3 | Android 6+, MIUI 8+ | working

Honor holly 2 plus | | working

Samsung J7 | | working

Moto g 3 | | working

---

```
GetLatLong(){
      this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        var myoption = {
            timeout:5000,
            enableHighAccuracy:true
          }

        this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(myoption).then(resp => {
          this.lattitude = resp.coords.latitude;
          this.longitude = resp.coords.longitude;
          this.location = "SUCCESS";
         })

        let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.lattitude, this.longitude);
        let mapOptions = {
           center: latLng,
           zoom: 14,
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
          }
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
          this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: this.map,
            zoom: 14,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: latLng,
          });
      })
  }
```

---

all detail describe in this link.

[for more detail refer this link](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/2156)